# RxJava: How to transform an unsteady source of events into a more frequent source of progress?

Tags: rx-java

I have an Observable (RxJava 1.x) with randomly occuring events:

```
    int numberOfItems = 10;
    Observable<Integer> unsteadyEvents = Observable.range(1, numberOfItems)
            .concatMap(progress ->
                    Observable.just(progress)
                            .delay(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(4), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            );
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    unsteadyEvents
            .map(progress -> "Progress " + progress + "/" + numberOfItems + " after " + stopwatch)
            .subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace, () -> System.out.println("Done."));
```

The output is e.g.

```
Progress 1/10 after 3.067 s
Progress 2/10 after 3.085 s
Progress 3/10 after 5.095 s
Progress 4/10 after 6.109 s
Progress 5/10 after 6.110 s
Progress 6/10 after 7.124 s
Progress 7/10 after 9.136 s
Progress 8/10 after 12.15 s
Progress 9/10 after 12.15 s
Progress 10/10 after 12.15 s
Done.
```

For the GUI, I'd like to have an output with a more frequent **progress event at least every second**:

```
Progress 0/10 after 1 s
Progress 0/10 after 2 s
Progress 0/10 after 3 s 
Progress 1/10 after 3.067 s
Progress 2/10 after 3.085 s
Progress 2/10 after 4 s
Progress 2/10 after 5 s
Progress 3/10 after 5.095 s
Progress 3/10 after 6 s
Progress 4/10 after 6.109 s
Progress 5/10 after 6.110 s
Progress 5/10 after 7 s
Progress 6/10 after 7.124 s
Progress 6/10 after 8 s
Progress 6/10 after 9 s
Progress 7/10 after 9.136 s
Progress 7/10 after 10 s
Progress 7/10 after 11 s
Progress 7/10 after 12 s
Progress 8/10 after 12.15 s
Progress 9/10 after 12.15 s
Progress 10/10 after 12.15 s
Done.
```

The idea is, that even if there is no "real progress", the user can see an update in the GUI with a new value from the stopwatch.

Question: How can I transform the unsteady source of events into a more frequent source of progress?

Hint: I'm looking for some kind of "combination" magic, not splitting the "real progress" and the "stopwatch event" into two separate Observable's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `interval` will never end, you can `materialize` both, so that your unsteady stream triggers completion:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
  unsteadyEvents.materialize(),
  Observable.interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).materialize(),
  (tick, update) -> update
)
              .dematerialize();
```

`[de]materialize` wraps and unwraps items in standard event objects for `onNext`, `onError` and `onComplete`. Critical here is that `interval` should only emit `onNext`, so you preserve all interesting events from `unsteadyEvents`. [See the docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/materialize-dematerialize.html).

Comment: thanks for the nice "trick" using materialize / dematerialize!

Comment: Observable#combineLatest is a static method in RxJava 1.x. Your example doesn't compile. Can you update the example? I tried to update it myself, but my edit was discarded in the peer review. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `withLatestFrom()` operator to coordinate 2 observables.

```
Observable.interval( 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS )
  .withLatestFrom( sourceOfSporadicUpdates, ( tick, update ) -> update )
```

This will provide a regular series of updates for your GUI, with the latest progress value.

Comment: Thanks for the effort Bob. It's not that easy I think... there are 2 issues with your solution: 1) the observable never completes 2) "real progress" events are skipped sometimes. Try it out.